# Are these SQL queries equivalent

Tags: sql, join

Let's say I have a table called Batch, which contains a name and a status for each Batch. The statuses are numeric. Another table, called BatchStatus, status numbers to human-readable strings. So the JOIN below lists all batch names and their statuses in human readable form:

```
SELECT b.Name, s.Description from Batch b JOIN BatchStatus s on b.StatusNbr = s.StatusNbr
```

I saw the above query in production code, Googled what JOIN does and understood that the query does what I described above. If I was writing the query myself (yesterday, before I learned about JOINs), I would have written it with a simple where clause:

```
select b.Name, s.Description from Batch b, BatchStatus s where b.StatusNbr = s.StatusNbr
```

Are these two queries equivalent? If so, why is the special JOIN syntax needed, when a simple WHERE clause already does the same thing?

Thanks!

Comment: The second statement is old-school SQL, and is deprecated in at least one RDBMS I know of. In practice they are equivalent.

Comment: Multiple duplicates. Use explicit `JOIN`.